# Normalization of states and bracket notation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, dirac-delta-distributions, normalization

In Peskin & Schroeder's QFT, if we set $$|p\rangle = \sqrt{2E_p} a^{\dagger}_p|0\rangle \tag{2.35}$$ as in equation 2.35, then how do I get to the next equation 2.36:

$$\langle p|q\rangle = 2E_p (2\pi)^3 \delta^3(p-q) \tag{2.36}
$$ 
Where I seem to be stuck is:
$$\langle p|q\rangle =\sqrt{2E_p 2E_q}\langle0|a_pa_q^{\dagger}|0\rangle
$$
I don't understand why $\langle0|a_pa_q^{\dagger}|0\rangle$ is prop. to the delta function.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/607029/how-to-compute-normalization-of-one-particle-states?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try commuting $a_p$ and $a_q^\dagger$ and keep in mind that $a_n|0\rangle = 0$.

Comment: so I get $\sqrt{2E_p2E_q} \langle 0 |a_p a_q^{\dagger}|0\rangle = \sqrt{2E_p2E_q} \langle 0 |[a_p ,a_q^{\dagger}]|0\rangle + \sqrt{2E_p2E_q} \langle 0 |a_q^{\dagger} a_p |0\rangle $. The second term is zero since $a_n |0\rangle = 0 \forall n$. So we get, using $[a_p, a_q^{\dagger}] = 1 $, $\sqrt{2E_p2E_q} \langle 0 |0\rangle$. But what is $\langle 0 |0\rangle$ equal to? Thank you

Comment: Depending on whether you have Bosonic or Fermionic operators, the bracket inside the first term after the $=$ sign is either a commutator or an anti-commutator. But, regardless, that bracket is a the delta function. So you have: $\sqrt{4E_pE_q}\langle 0|\delta^3(q - p)(2\pi)^3|0\rangle = \sqrt{4E_pE_q}\delta^3(q - p)(2\pi)^3\langle 0|0\rangle= \sqrt{4E_pE_q}\delta^3(q - p)(2\pi)^3 = $ the desired answer.

Comment: Thank you. And by definition $\langle s | s \rangle = 1$ for all states $s$, right?

Comment: No problem! And yes, for any normalised state, we have $\langle s|s\rangle = 1$. In other words, a state projects onto itself 100%.