# How to compute normalization of one-particle states for Klein-Gordon field quantization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, klein-gordon-equation, normalization

I am reading through Dr. Schwartz's book on quantum field theory; in section 2.3.1, he writes the following relation: $$\langle\mathbf{p}|\mathbf{k}\rangle=2\omega_p(2\pi)^3\delta^3(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{k})$$
where $\omega_p=|\mathbf{p}|$. Do note his conventions: $[\hat{a}_p,\hat{a}_k^\dagger]=(2\pi)^3\delta(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{k})$ and $\sqrt{2\omega_p}\hat{a}_p^\dagger|0\rangle=|\mathbf{p}\rangle$. However, when I do the (fairly trivial) calculation myself, I get
$$\begin{align}
\langle\mathbf{p}|\mathbf{k}\rangle&=2\sqrt{\omega_p\omega_k}\langle0|\hat{a}_p\hat{a}_k^\dagger|0\rangle \\
&=2\sqrt{\omega_p\omega_k}\left((2\pi)^3\delta(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{k})\langle0|0\rangle+\langle 0|\hat{a}_k^\dagger\hat{a}_p|0\rangle\right) \\
&=2\sqrt{\omega_k\omega_p}(2\pi)^3\delta(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{k})
\end{align}$$
I fail to see how $\sqrt{\omega_p\omega_k}=\omega_p$! Do I have some fundamental misunderstanding of the situation? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the calculation. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the effect of the $\delta(\mathbf p - \mathbf k)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since
$$\omega_p=\sqrt{\mathbf{p}^2+m^2}$$
and
$$f(x)\delta(x-y)=f(y)\delta(x-y) ,$$
in the sense of integration, you have
$$\sqrt{\omega_p}\delta(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{k})=\sqrt{\omega_k}\delta(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{k}) .$$

---

As pointed out by *John Dumancic* and *kaylimekay* in the comments below, the identities for the $\delta$ function are only meaningful when they are utilized in integration.
To be specific, one can perform substitution in the following expression
$$ \int {d\mathbf{p}}\rho(\mathbf{k})\sqrt{\omega_p}\delta(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{k})$$
to get
$$ \int {d\mathbf{p}}\rho(\mathbf{k})\sqrt{\omega_k}\delta(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{k})=\rho(\mathbf{k})\sqrt{\omega_k}\int {d\mathbf{p}}\delta(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{k})=\rho(\mathbf{k})\sqrt{\omega_k} .$$
But without the integral $\int d\mathbf{p}$, the identity/equality is not rigorously defined.
You may try to verify in your favorite textbook whether the identity is always utilized in the above context.

Comment: Is that legal to do outside of an integral? I thought it wasn't.

Comment: @JohnDumancic Delta functions themselves are not "legal" outside an integral, so every expression you write involving a delta function is understood to be an identity that holds under integration.

Comment: @kaylimekay "...so every expression you write involving a delta function is understood to be an identity that holds under integration." Could you be a little more specific please?

Comment: @rainman An expression with a delta function should be understood as you will use this identity to substitute a part of a (larger) expression (to achieve some derivation you need) where this delta function (in the latter expression) is eventually integrated out.

Comment: @gamebm By 'identity' what exactly is referred here?

Comment: I modified the answer to illustrate the use of the relation.

Comment: @gamebm Much appreciated!